Why does my allshortest pathfinding query return paths with cycles?
I'm using an allshortest pathfinding query in Memgraph. The edges connected to the center node have weights that are almost zero, which might be contributing to the problem. Is it expected for the allshortest pathfinding query to return paths with cycles under these conditions? If so, how can I modify the query to exclude paths that traverse through zero-weight edges?

Finding all shortest paths expands the weighted shortest paths problem and finds all similar-weighted paths. In your case, since you have 0-weight edges, I would say that this is the expected behavior because the algorithm can traverse them indefinitely, creating cycles. To prevent this, you can adjust your query to exclude 0-weight edges from traversal:
MATCH path=(:Node {id: 1})-[*ALLSHORTEST ..14 (r, n | r.weight) total_weight (r, n | r.weight > 0)]-(m:Node {id: 4})
RETURN path;

